# Angular 4 + springboot + Maven + Eclipse - Have to build everytime

Tags: angular, maven, spring-boot

I hope this a valid question. I didn't find a good solution after search over internet.

I am developing an application using Angular 4 + Spring boot with STS(Eclipse). I am using maven. I have to do "ng build" every time I make changes in angular. my exception is if I change anything in angular, it should reflect in web page without doing "ng build".

Here is my folder structure:

In below path, in command prompt, I am executing command: "mvn clean isntall" everytime I change anything in java:
[image: In command prompt, I am executing command: "mvn clean isntall" everytime I change anything in java]

In below path, in command prompt, I am executing command: "ng build" everytime I make change anything in angular
[image: In command prompt, I am executing command: "ng build" everytime I make change anything in angular]

I tried with "ng serve", But it didn't work, that means the mvn clean was successful, but I don't see the page when load in browser.

Comment: When you open your page in your browser you go to "localhost:SPRING_PORT" (default:8080) or you go to "localhost:4200" ?

Comment: http://localhost:8080

Comment: If I go 4200, then I may not be able to get the REST calls... Am I right?

Comment: You can call your rest API with 4200, but you might need a proxy or use the @CrossOrigin notation on your spring rest service

Comment: Ok, I think if I change the url in my service.ts from const url = '/api/updatecount/';    to    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/updatecount/';   then it may work.... I will try

Comment: @Y.Tarion: I am not aware of CrossOrigin notation. I will google it now. If any exmpales, that would be great. But I will also google it now

Comment: I tried changing my service.ts from const url = '/api/updatecount/'; to const url = 'localhost:8080/api/updatecount/';. But it din't work. May be because of CSRF or what I don't know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried with below command

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy-conf.json -o
```

Do remember that you need to have proxy-conf.json in your project. It should be in the same directory where package.json is. Then run localhost:4200

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider running Angular 4 project separately, outside of Spring project. And when you want to deploy/release then you just put Angular files to Spring project.

My setup for example:
Angular 4 running on :4200 locally.
Spring running on :8080 locally.

When I need to deploy a new version, I just put compressed angular files to Spring project folder and create War file with Maven.

Answer (score 0):

For development you can use `ng serve` in your angular app directory and start the backend seperatly. `ng serve` will automatically detect changes in your Angular files, rebuild and serve the new content.

For the complete deployment in the end you can use maven and build everything to one `war`. In your pom you can define also a plugin for `ng build` and a plugin to copy the dist directory of you Angular app to the correct location. The "dist" directory contains your build Android application (js files etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I am able to do by running Angular using "ng serve" and java using "mvn clean install". Bu tI had to a lot of changes. changes are:

1) in application.properties, I added

```
security.ignored=/**
```

2) WebSecurityConfiguration.java

```
//.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/resources/**", "/assets/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/fonts/**") -> Commented this line
  .antMatchers("/**")
. . .
. . .
. . .
http.cors();
```

3) Changed all REST calls with appending http://localhost:8080/. For example if it was

```
 this.http
            .get('api/inspection')
```

now it is:

```
 this.http
            .get('http://localhost:8080/api/inspection')
```

I am still looking for a better solution. That mean at least I don't have to change REST calls. I should have get('api/inspection'). And I want to use some kind of interceptor to add localhost:800 for me.