# Angular 4.0: Set base url for REST calls

Tags: angular

I am developing an Angular project with spring boot, maven and eclipse. I want to use "ng serve", so I don't have to build everytime. So I am trying to access the web page from Angular using 'ng serve' and get data from spring boot using REST calls. Now since I have a lot of REST calls already, I don't want to go each file and change the url to http://localhost:8080/api/inspection

I want to add http://localhost:8080 to all REST calls. I tried below code, but it is still calling http://localhost:**4200**/api/inspection

Created IqsInterceptor.ts:

```
import {  Injectable, } from '@angular/core';
import {  HttpRequest,  HttpHandler,  HttpEvent,  HttpInterceptor} from '@angular/common/http';
import {  Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class IqsInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080';
    req = req.clone({
      url: url + req.url
    });
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

Updated app.module.ts:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {AlertService} from './alert/alert.service';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpRequest, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

import {IqsInterceptor} from './IqsInterceptor';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        AppRoutingModule
    ],
    providers: [
        AppComponent,
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: IqsInterceptor, multi: true }

    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        . . . Other components
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

You can see my previous question for more information:
[Angular 4 + springboot + Maven + Eclipse - Have to build everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923239/angular-4-springboot-maven-eclipse-have-to-build-everytime)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can add a proxy-conf.json

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false
  }

}
```

And your npm start command would change to "`ng serve --proxy-config proxy-conf.json -o`"

Since Angular is running in Development server it would run in port 4200, and spring boot is running in port 8080. You can use the proxy conf to tell it to pass the data to a different host when you run it in your local environment.

Comment: what would be the path of proxy-conf.json ?

Comment: the same level where the package.json exists